# Implement Mail Client Functionality on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email

I want to implement the functionality some thing like a mail client on wordpress, my website has two types of user one is customer and another is vendor, customer can send inquiry/anything to the vendor, this message sent to vendor via a email as well as this thing saved into my worpress site (I'm using "Front End PM" plugin, it send email also and shows that email on customer inbox on wordpress site.), I need something like that when vendor reply on any customer inquiry on her personal email, that reply also shown on customer inbox of "Front End PM" plugin on wordpress site.

How can I achieve that, please share any idea. finally I need a mail client type (Outlook) thing on wordpress site for every customer type user.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not a place to dump your "I want" requirements list and expect others to build or design your system for you.

Comment: Yes I know that and also I'm not asking for anyone to implement the things for me, For your kind information I just need to know the idea how can I achieve this? or what things necessary for implement this? Or is it possible or not. Ahead of work is mine, I hope you understand.